# Set Mercury Up for the PHP Mail() Function

Tags: php, smtp

I'm just toying around with some PHP and I'm trying to use the mail() function successfully.  However, I get the error:

Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550-Verification failed for  550-No Such User Here" 550 Sender verify failed

My code, just in case there's something wrong:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Subscriber List</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    echo "<form method='POST' action='index.php' name='subscriber'>";
    echo   "Email: <input type='text' name='email'><br>";
    echo   "<button type='submit' name='subscribe'>Subscribe!</button>";
    echo "</form>";
  }

  if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $useremail = $_POST['email'];
    $to = 'myemail@workdomain.ca';
    $subject = 'New Subscriber';
    $message = "You have a ne subscriber from $useremail!";
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $headers = "From: The Sender Name <from@workdomain.ca>\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I Google it, it looks like I have to set up the SMTP server properly.  How do I go about doing that?  I'm using XAMPP with Mercury.